# Change text selection menu language

Tags: android, android-studio

I maintain a app.

When it show text selection menu,
the menu's text is not system default language.
(But its UI is system default language.)
[image]

Other app's text selection menu shows system default language.
[image]

(You can see the text selection menu'text is different.)

I want to text selection menu language show system default language.

What should I do??
Thank you.

Comment: Pls provide more details and read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)